# Cannot implicy convert type string[] to string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I'm having this problem, I'm getting a "Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string".

```
public class InventoryText : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerInventory Inventory;

    public Text TextInventory;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Inventory = GameObject.Find("Inventory").GetComponent<PlayerInventory>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        TextInventory.text = Inventory.Items;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Inventory.Items` is an array of strings. You can't use it as a string unless accessing a specific index.

Comment: ```Items``` is an array of strings. How would you like to represent the multiple strings in a single string? Just comma separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Items` is presumably a `string[]` (an array of strings). You can't just assign it to a string like `text`. One thing you could do is join them:

```
TextInventory.text = String.Join(", ", Inventory.Items);
```